# Error: Adobe creative SDK android

Tags: android, adobe, adobecreativesdk

I'm facing problems with some lines on the manifest while trying to work with creative SDK

and because am getting error from the stack that most of my post is code and that's not allowed I am typing this meaningless line :D :D "<3 luv u stack"

we are supposed to add the creative activity by this

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.aviary.android.feather.sdk.FeatherActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:process=":aviarysdk"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
        android:theme="@style/AviaryTheme.Dark" />
```

I get errors in both lines

```
android:process=":aviarysdk"
android:theme="@style/AviaryTheme.Dark"
```

My Error log is

```
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAdobeCreativesdkBehance0394Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAdobeCreativesdkFoundationAssets0394Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAdobeCreativesdkFoundationAuth0394Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAdobeCreativesdkImage400Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk401Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareItSephirothAndroidExifAndroidExifExtended106Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareItSephirothAndroidLibraryAbAbTest205Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareItSephirothAndroidLibraryDisklrumulticacheDisklrumulticache105Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareItSephirothAndroidLibraryHlistviewanimationsHlistviewanimationsLibrary101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareItSephirothAndroidLibraryHorizontallistviewHlistview131Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareItSephirothAndroidLibraryImagezoomImagezoom211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareItSephirothAndroidLibraryPicassoPicasso2353Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareItSephirothAndroidLibraryTargettooltipTargetTooltipLibrary124Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareItSephirothAndroidLibraryViewrevealanimatorViewRevealAnimator102Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareMyApplicationSlidingMenuLibUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareMyApplicationViewPagerIndicatorUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
D:\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.adobe.creativesdk\behance\0.3.94\AndroidManifest.xml
Warning:(15, 5) Element uses-permission#android.permission.INTERNET at com.adobe.creativesdk:behance:0.3.94:15:5 duplicated with element declared at com.adobe.creativesdk:behance:0.3.94:11:5
Warning:(16, 5) Element uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE at com.adobe.creativesdk:behance:0.3.94:16:5 duplicated with element declared at com.adobe.creativesdk:behance:0.3.94:12:5
Warning:(17, 5) Element uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at com.adobe.creativesdk:behance:0.3.94:17:5 duplicated with element declared at com.adobe.creativesdk:behance:0.3.94:13:5
Warning:(18, 5) Element uses-permission#android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE at com.adobe.creativesdk:behance:0.3.94:18:5 duplicated with element declared at com.adobe.creativesdk:behance:0.3.94:14:5
D:\MyApplication\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(67, 13) Attribute activity#com.aviary.android.feather.sdk.FeatherActivity@theme value=(@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:67:13
    is also present at com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0:39:13 value=(@style/AviaryTheme.Dark.Transition)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:61:9 to override
:app:processDebugManifest FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.948 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:4 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I am working with android studio

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

That means you have to replaced your aviary sdk to creative cloud of adobe, you can find the documentation and step by step explanation from here https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/211241666-Android-migration-guide-from-0-9-7-to-0-9-1062